# Unable to create a project in Android Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

[image: Uable to create a project]

I am a beginner of Android and Ubuntu. I downloaded every that promts. I dont know where I missed. I  am unable to start with create-a-project in Android Eclipse.

Comment: Since you are a beginner in Android, use Android Studio, not Eclipse. Ubuntu is also optional

Comment: My laptop is old one. It has some hardware problems and windows in not installing. And android studio hangs in this laptop.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search gave lots of solutions.Just try these.
1. Check for ADT and jdk updates.
2. Go to your eclipse installation folder and run "eclipse.exe -clean".

Start with Android Studio for android development as eclipse ADT is no longer supported
Read this https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html